# Jquery Get JSON Data

Tags: jquery, json

Can somebody help me to get JSON with JQuery? I think I am making some mistakes in my JQuery code. Any help will be appreciated. Below is my JSON and JQuery:

JSON:

```
{
    "video": [
        {
            "id": "12312412312",
            "name": "Ecuaciones Diferenciales",
            "url": "/video/math/edo/12312412312",
            "author": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name_author": "Alejandro Morales",
                        "uri": "/author/alejandro-morales",
                        "type": "master"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "comments": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "367501354973_12216733",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Doug Edwards",
                            "id": "628675309"
                        },
                        "message": "Make sure you don't, as they say, go whole hog...\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4wTFuaV8VQ",
                        "created_time": "2010-03-06T03:24:46+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "367501354973_12249673",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Tom Taylor",
                            "id": "1249191863"
                        },
                        "message": "Are you and Karen gonna, as they say, pig out?",
                        "created_time": "2010-03-06T21:05:21+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "367501354973_12249857",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Sheila Taylor",
                            "id": "1315606682"
                        },
                        "message": "how did it turn out? Sounds nummy!\n",
                        "created_time": "2010-03-06T21:10:30+0000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "12312412311",
            "name": "Ecuaciones Diferenciales : El arte de las diferenciaciones",
            "url": "/video/math/edo/1231241231212",
            "author": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name_author": "Alejandro Morales",
                        "uri": "/author/alejandro-morales",
                        "type": "master"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "comments": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "367501354973_12216733",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Doug Edwards",
                            "id": "628675309"
                        },
                        "message": "Make sure you don't, as they say, go whole hog...\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4wTFuaV8VQ",
                        "created_time": "2010-03-06T03:24:46+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "367501354973_12249673",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Tom Taylor",
                            "id": "1249191863"
                        },
                        "message": "Are you and Karen gonna, as they say, pig out?",
                        "created_time": "2010-03-06T21:05:21+0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "367501354973_12249857",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Sheila Taylor",
                            "id": "1315606682"
                        },
                        "message": "how did it turn out? Sounds nummy!\n",
                        "created_time": "2010-03-06T21:10:30+0000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

jQuery Code

```
var url = 'result.json';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(video, data) {
            $('#stage').html('<p> ID:' + data.video + '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p Name: ' + data.name+ '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p> URL: ' + data.url+ '</p>');

            console.log("========================");
            console.log(data);

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Need to be more specific about the actual problem you're having. I do see one issue with how you're trying to access your json - video is an array - you need to index into your array to be able to use properties like the ones I believe you're trying to access.

Comment: Can you please let me know code corrections?

Comment: Are you familiar with how arrays work? So data.video[0], for example, would reference the first element in the array. From that point data.video[0].id would reference the id property of the first element in the video array, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over the entire JSON object - you should iterate over one of its keys instead. Try this:

```
$.each(data.video, function(index, video) {
  $('#stage').append('<p> Name: ' + video.name+ '</p>');
  $('#stage').append('<p> URL: ' + video.url+ '</p>');
});
```

If you want to add additional data, you can traverse over the entire hierarchy. For example:

```
$.each(data.video, function(index, video) {
  $('#stage').append('<p> Name: ' + video.name + '</p>');
  $('#stage').append('<p> URL: ' + video.url + '</p>');

  $.each(video.author.data, function(index, author) {
    $('#stage').append('<p> Author: ' + author.name_author + '</p>');
  });

  $('#stage').append('<br/>');
});
```

Finally, if you want to access the n-th record, using the syntax above, you could do:

```
// n is the 0-based position of the json record you're interested in displaying
var video = data.video[n];
$('#stage').append('<p> Name: ' + video.name + '</p>');
$('#stage').append('<p> URL: ' + video.url + '</p>');
// etc...
```

Working example here: http://livecoding.io/3495017

Comment: How can I get further more data point like comments/ data and author.... Also unable to get  `$('#stage').append('<p Name: ' + value.name+ '</p>');`

Comment: Fixed the incorrect value.name. Regarding more data, exactly what structure do you want?

Comment: Just would like to spit data on page to have better understating of accessing data

Comment: Awesome, Last question :) how to get only one specific record from json?

Answer (score 4):

I'm  *guessing* you're trying to loop through each item in the `video` array that is a property of your `data` object, given that within your `$.each()` loop you're trying to access `.video`, `.name` and `.url` properties. So instead of:

```
 $.each(data, function(video, data) {
```

...which is looping through each top-level property of `data`, try:

```
 $.each(data.video, function(video, data) {
```

...to loop just through the items in the `data.video` array.

Also, given that the two parameters in that callback are the current item index and the current item I'd probably rename the parameters from `video` and `data` to `i` and `item`. It's a little confusing having different variables both called `data` (one being the parameter of the `$.getJSON()` callback, the other being a parameter of your `$.each()` callback).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to iterate over the wrong part of your JSON. I believe your $.each line should look like this:

```
$.each(data.video, function(index, video){
  // video.name, video.url, etc
}
```